# NReco PhantomJs with more then 5 PDF pages

Tags: .net, phantomjs, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

Running  phantomJs.RunScript() with data more then 45K that produces more then 5 PDF pages throws exception. Seems that is memory issue b/c simple running PnantomJs (without NReco : http://www.nrecosite.com/) with the same data works good.

Any ideas? How to tune memory or else...

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to provide 45K data with command line arguments ( jsArgs parameter of RunScript method) an exception might be caused by the limitation of the command line length (8Kb in most cases). I recommend to provide large datasets using stdin (see appropriate RunScript overload that accepts Stream for phantomjs input or output).